# How to save a webpage state(having dynamically added content), so it can be reloaded next time

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a webpage on which contents are also added dynamically using ajax. For example adding images though image and add draggable to it using jquery so they can be dragged.

Now , i want to save the state of webpage after images are added and are made draggable, so if user navigates away from page and again come back to same page using a link, he is able to see his added images and can also drag it.

How this can be achieved using jquery or anything. I dont have a clue about how we can do this. Any pointers to this will be of great help.

I am using php and jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the state in some hidden field with javascript and access that hidden field through ajax call or post back with server side code (php). Extract the state of page interpret it and save in some persistent medium like database.

Comment: Sorry, can you please elaborate on this.

Comment: It would be easier for me if you tell me what you understand and what needs explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use html5 web storage concepts for saving state of your page. `sessionStorage` would be easiest to implement.
You can find code samples of `sessionStorage` and other storage types [here](http://playground.html5rocks.com/#sessionStorage).

If `html5` is not an option then you can use `cookies` to store the state of page. You can access `cookies` via `Javascript`. You can also use `jquery` plugin [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) for easy implementation.

You can also find more discussion on [How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)

Comment: Sorry HTML5 is not a opiton for me :(

Comment: You can also use cookies to save the state.